# Memset enum array values not setting correctly (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, enums, memset

I'm trying to use memset to set all values in an enum array to a single value, but I'm not seeing the correct results.  The first memset works, the second does not.  My code:

```
// definitions
#define NUM_THREADS     1

enum ThreadState
{
    INITIALIZING,
    READY_TO_CALCULATE,
    CALCULATED,
    READY_TO_UPDATE,
    UPDATED
};


// Later on, in the code...
ThreadState Thread_States[NUM_THREADS];

// Somehow this works - after this statement, every entry in Thread_States is INITIALIZING
memset(Thread_States, INITIALIZING, NUM_THREADS* sizeof(ThreadState));

// ... later on (or even immediately right after) ...

// Failure - after this statement, every entry in Thread_States is 16843009
memset(Thread_States, READY_TO_CALCULATE, NUM_THREADS* sizeof(ThreadState));
```

As explained in the comments, the first time I call memset, the values are set to what I expect (INITIALIZING, i.e., 0).  When I run the second statement, I don't see the values set to READY_TO_CALCULATE (i.e., 1).  Rather, they're set to 16843009, when I check the debugger.

Is there a reason this relatively simple use of memset is inconsistent in its behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: The sizeof() an enum is int, not char.

Comment: Imagine the dataype for your enum is 4 bytes, memset sets every value to 0x02020202, probably not what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `memset` function sets *each byte* of the memory to the second argument (after the second argument is truncated). As enumerations are (normally) the size of `int` you will get the wrong result. The only time it will work is for an enumeration value of zero, as it will then set all bytes to zero.

If you use e.g. `READY_TO_CALCULATE` you will set each byte to `1`, which will create `int` values of `0x01010101` instead of `0x00000001`.

Comment: It will also work for -1. Since it will set each byte as `ff` and `ffffffff` is also equal to -1

Comment: @DollarAkshay I think C and C++ differs in that regards. IIRC C doesn't yet require two's complement representation of negative numbers, but C++ do. And that's besides the issue that `-1` is not as easy to understand at a quick glance as `0xff`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question C or C++?

In case of C, remember to loop over the array to set each value, as memset is just not meant for this kind of function. You're trying to set elements, not memory.

In case of C++, use an enum class for the state. Also, try to encapsulate your thread state in its own class that manages it, and make the default initializer construct it properly.